# Ordering array of strings in bash scripting

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting, scripting

I am fairly new to bash scripting. I have a list of files in my directory and I'd like to store them into an array and then sort them inside the array. I've stored the list of files into my array; however, I'm unable to order them.

```
  for file in test_file*.txt;
  do
    TEST_FILE="${file##*/}"
    arrayname[index]=$TEST_FILE
    index=$(expr $index + 1)
  done
```

That stores all the files starting with test_file and ending with .txt into my array. The part that I find tricky is sorting it. I've done a bit of digging around, but I could not find the solution.

Also if I was so run compile a python code later, would I do a loop and call

```
python3 test.py "$arrayname[n]"
```

and increment n?

My current directory has these files and it is stored in the array "arrayname[]" in the form:

```
 test_file0.txt, test_file12.txt, test_file11.txt, test_file10.txt,
```

I am trying to sort it and store it into another array, so the new array has the following order:

```
 test_file0.txt, test_file10.txt, test_file11.txt, test_file12.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean _sorting it_? Can you show an actual example and let us know what you are trying?

Comment: updated the post. Currently my array consist of: test_file0.txt, test_file12.txt, test_file11.txt, test_file10.txt

and the output I need is:  test_file0.txt, test_file10.txt, test_file11.txt, test_file12.txt

Comment: When I created some sample files as `touch test_file0.txt test_file12.txt test_file11.txt test_file10.txt` and echo'd manually as  `for file in test_file*.txt;   do  echo "$file"; done`, it is in sorted order only

Comment: @Engah: The logic is _pathname expansion_ in `bash` to list files always appears in sorted order

Comment: he probably mean sorted numerically... `1,2,10` and not `1,10,2`

Comment: @anubhava This is actually a bit weird. I just tried `echo test_file*.txt` and it ordered it like this `test_file0.txt test_file10.txt test_file11.txt test_file12.txt test_file13.txt test_file14.txt test_file15.txt test_file16.txt test_file17.txt test_file18.txt test_file19.txt test_file1.txt test_file20.txt test_file21.txt test_file22.txt test_file23.txt test_file24.txt test_file25.txt` I have up to 50 files

Comment: Ideally, I would like the output to be  `test_file0.txt test_file1.txt test_file2.txt ... test_file50.txt` then store all of them into another array.

Comment: Check out the sort command and the -n option or perhaps better -V

Answer (score 1):

If your `sort` knows the `-V` (GNU sort):

```
readarray -t files < <(printf "%s\n" test_file* | sort -V)
printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}"

#bash 4.4+
readarray -t -d '' files1 < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name test_file\* -print0 | sort -zV)
printf "%s\n" "${files1[@]}"
```